# AWS SSM describe-instance-information doesn't find my instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-ssm

I am using boto3 to control my EC2 instances on AWS from a python environment, using ec2 and ssm services. I have created an IAM account, that has access to AmazonSSMFullAccess and AmazonEC2FullAccess policies.

```
ec2 = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    region_name='eu-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='…',
    aws_secret_access_key='…/…+…'
)

ssm = boto3.client(
    'ssm',
    region_name='eu-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='…',
    aws_secret_access_key='…/…+…'
)
```

I ran:

```
ec2.describe_instances()['Reservations']
```

Witch returned a list of all my instances.
But when I run:

```
ssm.describe_instance_information()
```

I get an empty list, though I have at least one instance running on AWS Linux AMI (ami-ca0135b3), and six others on recent Ubuntu AMIs. They are all in eu-west-1 (Ireland).
They should have SSM Agent preinstalled : (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html)

I sshed into the AWS Linux instance, and tried to get the logs for ssm using:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log
```

But nothing happens there when I run my python code. A sequence of messages gets displayed from time to time :

```
HealthCheck reporting agent health.
error when calling AWS APIs. error details - NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
```

I also tried running a command through the web interface, selected '    AWS-RunRemoteScript' but no instance is shown below.

My goal is to run:

```
ssm.send_command(
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={'commands': [command]},
        InstanceIds=[instance_id],
    )
```

But it gives me the following error, probably due to the previous problem.

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The agent is pre-installed, but the **instance** (not just your IAM user) still needs the proper role to communicate with the systems manager. Particularly [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-configuring-access-role.html) step of [Configuring Access to Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-access.html).

> By default, Systems Manager doesn't have permission to perform actions
>   on your instances. You must grant access by using an IAM instance
>   profile. An instance profile is a container that passes IAM role
>   information to an Amazon EC2 instance at launch.

You should review the whole configuration guide and make sure you have configured all required roles appropriately.

Comment: Indeed. EC2 Instance profile should include role ```AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore```